# How to use Laravel Passport with Password Grant Tokens?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I just read the https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport documentation and I have some doubts that hopefully someone could help me with:

First, some context, I want to use Passport as a way to provide Oauth authentication for my mobile app (first-party app).

1. When I use `php artisan passport:client --password` I get back a Client ID and a Client Secret. Does this value have to be fixed on my app? for example storing them hardcoded or as a "settings" file? If the values shouldn't be stored then how should it work?
2. To register a user to my app I use: `$user->createToken('The-App')->accessToken;` I get that the accessToken will be the one used for sending on all my requests as a Header (Authorization => Bearer $accessToken) but what exactly is "The-App" value for?
3. For login the user I'm using the URL: http://example.com/oauth/token and sending as parameters:

   {
       "username": "user@email.com",
       "password": "userpassword",
       "grant_type": "password",
       "client_id": 1, // The Client ID that I got from the command (question 1)
       "client_secret": "Shhh" // The Client Secret that I got from the command (question 1)
   }
4. When I login the user using the previous endpoint I get back a refresh_token, I read that I could refresh the token through http://example.com/oauth/token/refresh but I try to request the refresh I got Error 419, I removed the url oauth/token/refresh from the csrf verification and now I get back `"message": "Unauthenticated."`, I'm making the following request:

   Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
   grant_type: refresh_token
   refresh_token: the-refresh-token // The Refresh Token that I got from the command (question 3) 
   client_id: 1  // The Client ID that I got from the command (question 1) 
   client_secret: Shhh // The Client Secret that I got from the command (question 1)
   scope: ''

Should I use this endpoint? or is not necessary given the app I'm trying to develop.

5. Finally, there are a lot of endpoints that I get from passport that I don't think I will use for example: `oauth/clients*`, `oauth/personal-access-tokens*` is there a way to remove them from the endpoints published by passport?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For password grant you cannot use `$user->createToken('The-App')->accessToken;` for generating access token

Comment: Hi @Wellwisher can you tell me why I can not use that option?

Comment: That option is for generating personal access token and in your code you have used the password grand. To generate token use this method https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#requesting-password-grant-tokens

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are consuming your own api then you don't need to call  [http://example.com/oauth/token](http://%20http://example.com/oauth/token)
for user login because then you need to store client_id and client_secret at app side. Better you create an api for login and there you can check the credentials and generate the personal token.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
             $user = Auth::user();
             $token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;

            return response()->json($token);
        }
}
```

> Finally, there are a lot of endpoints that I get from passport that I
>   don't think I will use for example: oauth/clients*,
>   oauth/personal-access-tokens* is there a way to remove them from the
>   endpoints published by passport?

You need to remove `Passport::routes();` from AuthServiceProvider and manually put only required passport routes. I think you only need `oauth/token` route.

> what exactly is "The-App" value for?

if you check **oauth_access_tokens** table it has name field. `$user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;` here the **"Token Name"** stored in name field.

> How to use Laravel Passport with Password Grant Tokens?

To generate password grant token you have to store `client_id` and `client_secret` at app side (not recommended, check [this](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth/issues/170)  ) and suppose if you have to reset the `client_secret` then the old version app stop working, these are the problems. To generate password grant token you have to call this api like you mention in step 3.

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        'password' => 'my-password',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

> Generate token from `refresh_token`

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => 'the-refresh-token',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'scope' => '',
    ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

**You can look this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#implicit-grant-tokens too.**

Comment: https://jagadeshanh.wordpress.com/2016/12/27/using-laravel-passport-for-api-authentication/ wrote this little long ago. Still it can be used as a reference.

Comment: just curious, I have been consuming APIs since years, API providers always give the client_id and client_secret for authentication. why do we need email and password here in laravel passport?

Comment: @amansoni211 yes you are right but in that case we generally call those api from server side. Here the question is to use the `client_id` and `client_secrect` at app side and for that you can not store it at client side. Hope it may clear you

Comment: @rkj Well explained, Thanks. What method of authentication would you suggest [in passport] if need to expose my api to business partners who will eventually access my APIs from their web servers?

Answer (score 7):

Tackling Question 5

> Finally, there are a lot of endpoints that I get from passport that I don't think I will use for example:  `oauth/clients*`, `oauth/personal-access-tokens*` is there a way to remove them from the endpoints published by passport?

---

`Passport::routes($callback = null, array $options = [])` takes an optional `$callback` function and optional `$options` argument.

The callback function takes a `$router` argument from which you can then choose which routes to install as shown below in your `AuthServiceProvider.php` that is enabling a more granular configuration:

```
Passport::routes(function ($router) {
    $router->forAccessTokens();
    $router->forPersonalAccessTokens();
    $router->forTransientTokens();
});

Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10));

Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(10));
```

This way we only create the passport routes that we need.

`forAccessTokens()`; enable us to create access tokens. 
`forPersonalAccessTokens()`; enable us to create personal tokens although we will not use this in this article. Lastly, 
`forTransientTokens()`; creates the route for refreshing tokens.

If you run `php artisan route:list` you can see the new endpoints installed by Laravel Passport.

```
| POST | oauth/token         | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken
| POST | oauth/token/refresh | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\TransientTokenController@refresh
```