# Login api route always return 200

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I've created a Laravel API that is consumed by a Vue front-end. It works fine locally, I have now deployed it to a staging server and my `/login` route does not work - it returns a 200 status with no response text regardless of whether the credentials are correct or not, the response text should contain the `access_token` or an error in JSON.

My process was to deploy by git, use composer to set up the dependencies, setup mySQL, configure the `.env` file, migrate the database, run `php artisan passport:install`, configure the `.env` file again with the client secret and id, create a user with `tinker`, using Postman I hit the endpoint `/oauth/token`with the necessary data and I successfully get the Bearer token, I can hit `/user` with the Bearer token and get the corresponding user. Trying log in either through Postman or Vue I get them problem stated previously.

Here is the network tab of the request.

[image]

AuthController.php

```
public function login(Request $request) 
{
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    try {
        $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ]
         ]);
         return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);

     } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
                return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
            } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
                return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
            }
            return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
     }
}
```

Debug is set to true, the I've checked in the log and the only error is this:

```
[2018-07-19 13:12:01] production.ERROR: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. {"exception":"[object] (League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Exception\\OAuthServerException(code: 9): T$
[stacktrace]
```

However after searching Google I don't know if this is relevant. How can I better debug this? Does anyone know of a solution, any pointers wouldbe greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `$e->getStatusCode()` instead `$e->getCode()`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, I made the change but I still don't get any response text

Comment: that means your code is not trowing error and `$response->getBody()` is empty

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on ways to find out why that is the case?

Comment: you might have something mismatch at your server. if you are using your own api then you could have use `personal token` check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848892/how-to-use-laravel-passport-with-password-grant-tokens