# How to retrieve Laravel Passport access token expiration duration or datetime?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and Passport 4. I want to use only `First-Party-App` only. So as suggested from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50849813/5565544), I want to stay away from putting the ClientID and ClientSecret in the App. I have put in `boot()` method of `AuthServiceProvider`  :

```
Passport::routes();
Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(60));
```

I added my own route in `api.php` to accept login from App :

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@apiLogin');
```

This is my Action :

```
public function apiLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        $user = Auth::user();
        $token = $user->createToken('API Access')->accessToken;

        return response()->json(["token_type" =>"Bearer","expires_in" => 2592000,"access_token" => $token]);
    }

    return response()->json(["error" => "invalid_credentials", "message" => "The user credentials were incorrect."], 401);
}
```

Is there any method to retrieve the number of seconds for `expires_in` (30 days => 2592000s), or the datetime so I could make the calculation automatically?

Comment: You should be able to access the `expiry` property on `$token`. What does your JSON response look like for `access_token`? Also, if you can't access it, you could always do `$expire = Carbon::now()->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now()->addDays({days}));` and return that instead of `2592000`, but that seems like a long way to go about getting `{days} * 86400`

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim Lewis! I could access it with $token which is an Eloquent Model containing the tokens : `$objToken = $user->createToken('API Access');` and I did `$expire = $objToken->token->expires_at->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now());`.
However `Passport::tokensExpireIn((new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval('P30D')));` does not work, seems like a bug in Laravel 5.4 from many discussions ignoring it. A chance that I wanted it from the property itself... But that's another problem.
Anyway I you post it as an Answer then I will choose it as answered.

Comment: Nice; glad you got it working. For the second concern, when working with Laravel, you have access to `Carbon`, so you shouldn't have to use `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes; any reason you're trying that particular code vs `Carbon::now()->addDays(30)`? Also, go ahead and post a self answer; I simply pointed you in the correct direction :)

Comment: Thanks for the Carbon suggestion. When I was using Laravel 4, I didn't know much about Carbon. Now that I'm more into Laravel 5+, I'm changing some habits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how I managed to get it from the object:

As Tim Lewis  pointed me in the comments, there is a $token property, `$user->createToken('API Access')` is a `Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessTokenResult` object that contains 2 public properties : `$accessToken (String)` and `$token (Laravel\Passport\Token)`. So I get the token with `$objToken = $user->createToken('API Access');` and calculate expiration time in seconds with `$expiration = $objToken->token->expires_at->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now());`. Here is the final code :

```
public function apiLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...

        Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(60));

        $user = Auth::user();
        $objToken = $user->createToken('API Access');
        $strToken = $objToken->accessToken;

        $expiration = $objToken->token->expires_at->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now());

        return response()->json(["token_type" => "Bearer", "expires_in" => $expiration, "access_token" => $strToken]);
    }

    return response()->json(["error" => "invalid_credentials", "message" => "The user credentials were incorrect."], 401);
}
```

But be careful if using these 2 lines in AuthServiceProvider boot() :

```
Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(60));
```

as it won't replace the expiration with Personal Access Token in Password Grant Type of Laravel 5.4 according to this [Laravel Passport Issue](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/162).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//...
use Laravel\Passport\Bridge\PersonalAccessGrant;
use League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer;
//...

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // http://php.net/manual/zh/dateinterval.construct.php
        $lifetime = new \DateInterval('P1W');

        $this->app->get(AuthorizationServer::class)
              ->enableGrantType(
                 new PersonalAccessGrant(), 
                 $lifetime
              );
    }

    //...
}
//...
```

Comment: Code is always good but it also helps to add some comments/context around how this addresses the original question.