# Auth::id() returns null laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a function where

```
public function index(){
   $users = User::doesntHave('roles')->latest()->paginate()->except(Auth::id());
   return UsersResource::collection($users);
}
```

when i dd the `Auth::id()` it returns null even if I declared the auth facade on my controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

this is my route which is stored inside `api.php`

```
Route::resource('users','Users\AdminUsersController')->except([
    'create', 'edit'
]);
```

Comment: which version of laravel  you are using?

Comment: check this `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: you route should have either `auth` middleware  or in your controller `__construct`         `$this->middleware('auth');`

Comment: I'll try later sir. Does it work even it is inside api route?

Comment: in api case you have to use `auth:api`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your auth protected routes inside `auth:api` middleware

```
Route::post('login','LoginController@login');

Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {

    Route::resource('users','Users\AdminUsersController')->except([
    'create', 'edit'
    ]);

    //other authenticated Routes goes inside this block

});
```

For Api authentication i suggest you to look https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport

Comment: sir it says unauthenticated status 401 do i need to install the passport?

Comment: @Beginner yes, need to install laravel passport and then need to generate accessToken and then send that token in header. you can look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848892/how-to-use-laravel-passport-with-password-grant-tokens

Comment: Sir sorry this is my first time implementing passport, i always skipped this one because i dont know where to start. So for example I have a login controller that generates access token. So in my route when I login, I can now already used the auth:api middleware and be able to consume my own api? localhost/app/public/api/users? w/o getting the 401 status? Thanks sir

Comment: yes, put your login controller outside of `auth:api` middleware Route block updated answer. After login and generated `accessToken` then use this accessToken in `Authorization` header like this `Authorization: Bearer accessToken` to call all protected apis. Side note it is good practice to use virtual host for laravel application. check here https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/584/how-to-configure-a-virtual-host-for-a-laravel-project-in-xampp-for-windows

Comment: meaning if i make a request from front end to backend i will always append that access token? based on my research they typically store the token on localstorage is that safe enough?

Comment: yes, for all request you have to append `Authorization` header with `accessToken` value. Yes, you can store it in localstorage. Remember `$user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken` generate a personal token and it doesn't have expire time so you have to revoke it either in your logout api or something like that. Better read the documentation from the link which is in answer

Comment: sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156606/laravel-multiple-database-connection-get-average-from-3-tables

Comment: sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171438/laravel-cronjob-run-whats-inside-the-method?noredirect=1#comment91293504_52171438

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52207683/get-latest-from-different-relationship-eloquent-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Are you're signed in. It doesn't sound like it.

Don't  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; instead it is just **use Auth**;.

You can do the following:

```
auth()->check(); // this checks to see if you're logged in

$userId = auth()->check() ? auth()->id() : null;

auth()->id(); // this is the same as Auth::id();

auth()->user();
```

Comment: "_Don't use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;_" Why not?

Answer (score 0):

$users = User::doesntHave('roles')->latest()->paginate()->except(Auth::user()->id);