# Laravel - multiple database connection get average from 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 databases

db_1    (students table)

```
id | students
1  | 42
```

db_2    (students table)

```
id | students
1  | 31
```

db_3    (students table)

```
id | students
1  | 22
```

In my controller, how can i get the total average of all students by using only one model (Student). and by just overriding the database connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important bit is the **setConnection()** method called on Model before querying. Remember that using it this way you need all the connections defined in your **config/database.php** under connections.

```
class StudentsController extends Controller {
        const DB_COUNT = 3;
        private $students;
        public function __construct(Students $students) {
            $this->students = $students;
        }

        public function index(Request $request) {
            for ($i=0; $i<self::DB_COUNT; $i++) { //or foreach through config('database.connections', [])
               $this->students->setConnection('db_'.($i+1));
               $students[] = $this->students->find(1)->students;
            }
            //what is "totalAVG" ???
            $totalAvg = array_sum($students) / self::DB_COUNT;
        }
    }
```

Alternatively if we want to stick to particular connection names:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
                foreach (config('database.connections', []) as $connName => $params)
                   $this->students->setConnection($connName);
                   $students[] = $this->students->find(1)->students;
                }
                //what is "totalAVG" ???
                $totalAvg = !empty($students) ? array_sum($students) / count($students) : 0;
            }
```

Comment: sir what if the name of databases is like these olfu, sti, mja

Comment: it's not the database name which matters - it's the connection name. In config/database.php under connections you define connection name and its parameters. Each connection may have the same database name on different host or different database name on same host etc...

Comment: sorry i mean the connection name on this line $this->students->setConnection('db_'.($i+1)); what if they have different connection names like for example olfu, sti, mja

Comment: then replace the for loop with foreach (config('database.connections', []) as $connName => $params) and do $this->students->setConnection($connName);

Comment: edited the answer to provide the alternative approach

Comment: sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171438/laravel-cronjob-run-whats-inside-the-method?noredirect=1#comment91293504_52171438