# Get latest item in a Laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 Tables

**Model Url**

```
class Url extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
    public function url_status(){
        return $this->hasMany(UrlStatus::class);
    }
}
```

**Model UrlStatus**

```
class UrlStatus extends Model
{
    public function url()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Url::class);
    }
}
```

**Model User**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, SoftDeletes, HasRoles;
    public function urls(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Url::class);
    }
}
```

In my controller I'm querying :

```
$url = Url::with('url_status','users')->where('list_status', true)->get();
```

How can I get the latest url_status?

EDIT ---

This is my structure for each table in migration file

**FOR URLS TABLE**

```
 Schema::create('urls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->boolean('list_status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**URL STATUS**

```
Schema::create('url_status', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('url_id');
            $table->integer('status_code');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->boolean('sms');
            $table->boolean('email');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**USERS TABLE**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('contacts');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by _latest_? Based on what? `id` or `date` or ... ?

Comment: date by column created_at

Comment: Querying for multiple `Url` models first and attaching each's `UrlStatus` models won't really get you the latest `UrlStatus` models per-say. Might make more sense to query `UrlStatus` directly, with `latest`, and attach `Url` instead. That, or run a `join` first and order by `url_status.created_at, DESC`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try it like this too

Model Url

```
public function latestUrlStatus(){
    return $this->hasOne(UrlStatus::class)->latest();
}
```

Fetch it like this

```
$urls = Url::with('latestUrlStatus','users')->where('list_status', true)->get();
foreach($urls as $url){
    echo $url->latestUrlStatus->status_code;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `latest()` method with `first()` like :

```
$url = Url::with('url_status','users')->where('list_status', true)->whereHas('url_status', function($q){
     $q->latest()->first();
})->get();
```

If you're trying to get the latest `url_status` for a given URL it could be done like :

```
$url->url_status->latest()->first();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'urls.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `url_status` where `urls`.`id` = `url_status`.`url_id` order by `created_at` desc limit 1)

Comment: You should check your relations then, since `url_status` belongs to `url` it should definitely contain the `url_id` field

Comment: whereHas is used to query relation existence, it doesn't affect the eager loading.

Comment: I think you need the latest URL status for every `$url`, if so check my update @Beginner