# laravel passport api authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I'm new to `api authentication` (passport) in laravel.
Is it possible to guard api routes using

```
$this->middleware('auth:api');
```

even if used the laravel built in authentication 
`(php artisan make:auth)`?

Comment: Yes you can, here is a good tutorial https://medium.com/modulr/create-api-authentication-with-passport-of-laravel-5-6-1dc2d400a7f

Comment: page not found.

Comment: It's working my end, try https://medium.com/modulr/create-api-authentication-with-passport-of-laravel-5-6-1dc2d400a7f

Comment: he make his own controller for authentication. My question is, is it possible to guard the api route even if used the php artisan make:auth

Comment: There's a manual page [API Authentication (Passport)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport). Does this help?

Comment: Check [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#stateless-http-basic-authentication) about Stateless HTTP Basic Authentication

Comment: @Beginner yes you can guard your api with `auth:api`, you just need to change the `api` guard driver to `passport` in `config/auth.php`

Comment: It will have no problem even if I used the laravel's built in authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can guard your api with `auth:api`, just need to change the api guard driver to passport in `config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            //'driver' => 'token',
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: I see, sometimes it confused me because i see other people make their own controller for authentication to get the response token

Comment: they created it like this $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token'); on their login controller. And use the response token to make an api call on frontend.

Comment: Now how can I get the token in frontend, If I used the laravel's built in auth?

Comment: to generate token, either you have to use passport endpoint or need to create your own controller. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848892/how-to-use-laravel-passport-with-password-grant-tokens

Comment: It is advisable to make own controller for login? to generate token?

Comment: not necessary always, check laravel passport has different route endpoints https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/2.0/src/RouteRegistrar.php and can be use it to generate token. As i said depend on requirement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620707/error-status-401-error-unauthenticated-laravel-passport?noredirect=1#comment92175149_52620707