# error status 401 error unauthenticated laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, axios, laravel-passport

This is my first time implementing laravel passport

This is my `config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

and this is where my `routes/api.php` that are guarded by `auth:api`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::resource('users','Users\AdminUsersController')->except([
    'create', 'edit'
    ]);
});
```

and this is how I fetch the api

```
fetchUsers: async function(page_url){
     await axios.get('api/users')
     .then( response => {
          vm.users = response.data.data;
      })
     .catch( error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
 },
```

Im getting status 401 error unauthenticated. How can I fix this? TIA

Comment: Are you sending the `authtoken or csrf token` in the header or not?

Comment: just pass `Authorization` header with data as `Bearer your_token`

Comment: how can I pass that? Im using laravel built in authentication via the command php artisan make:auth

Comment: sry im just new to this

Comment: @Beginner best article for Laravel with passport https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

Comment: all of the tutorials make their own controller for login. Im using the laravel's built in auth

Answer (score 0):

When a user logged in you want to pass his token.

```
$user = Auth::user();
return response()->json([
  'message'=>'You are logge in.',
  'token'=>$user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
]);
```

And you want to send that token as a http header when you sending data after a user logged. Laravel get the logged user details by this token. This is the header.

```
'Authorization: Bearer '+token_when_logged_in
```

This is how headers setup in axios (I am not familiar with axios)

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Comment: where to put this? im using laravel's built in auth the php artisan make:auth

Comment: After logged in via API you can put `axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';` in the success callback

Answer (score -1):

In your **Kernel.php** file and **protected $middlewareGroups** , comment or remove **'auth:api'** in :

```
'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            //'auth:api',
        ],
```