# Is it possible to create Client Tokens while passport-authenticated in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

So i've made an API with the guidance of Laravel's documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#issuing-access-tokens) and this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848892/how-to-use-laravel-passport-with-password-grant-tokens). One problem i encountered was that OAuth can only be accessed if I am authenticated with `Auth`.

However, since the application i am making is API only, i was wondering how i could use `auth:api` as my middleware for oauth links instead of `auth`. The result that should happen would be that i could create clients when i am authenticated with `Auth:Api`.

Route:List
[image]

How I'm currently authenticating my users (This is just a reference i took from the documentation):

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
  'form_params' => [
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => 'client-id',
    'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
    'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
    'password' => 'my-password',
    'scope' => '',
   ],
]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

AuthServiceProvider has:

```
 Passport::Routes()
```

Lastly, is it possible to set the expire of an individual personal access token?

Comment: If you are creating an API only software you can insert your routes in `routes/api.php` instead of `routes/web.php`. In this way, your API routes will start with `/api` prefix and will use `auth:api` middleware.

Comment: Whit `I could create clients when I am authenticated` you mean create new users when you are logged in?

Comment: @Stefano by clients i mean with the oauth/clients (Client ID + Secret). I understand how the `routes/api,php` works. I was wondering how i could access routes such as the oauth/clients route when i am authenticated as `auth:api` instead of `auth`

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your config/auth.php to utilize passport for API authentication?

**config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport', #Right here
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport

Comment: Yea i did! My problem is that when i do localhost/oauth/clients with postman with the token.. it gives me a routing error since it looks for the login route of auth - since ofc, the route uses auth instead of auth:api

Comment: @DeathKing Can you post the routing error you are getting? Also when you are trying to access /oauth/clients, are you sending the token within the headers as: Authentication : Bearer $token?

Comment: `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [login] not defined.` <<-- When i execute the postman and if i make the route (My custom login since `Auth` doesn't work with API, i get a `401 Unauthenticated Error` Also, i'm using Authorization Bearer [Token] and Accept Application/json as my headers.

Comment: @DeathKing In regards to utilizing the built-in route for creating clients, I am unsure. However, you could create a route, controller and model for oauth clients and write to the 'oauth_clients' table to create a new client.