# Understanding Laravel Passport refresh token

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I am trying to understand how to use Laravel Passport with email and password.

I know that I should not store client_id & client_secret on client side.
I wrote my own login and it's working as expected, in return I get the accesstoken, but I can't think of a way to refresh this token **without** storing client_id & client_secret on client.
Or is there no way to refresh the accesstoken without client_id & client_secret?

Also have read [How to use Laravel Passport with Password Grant Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848892/how-to-use-laravel-passport-with-password-grant-tokens) but there is no clear answer for me how and if it is possible to refresh token.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/

> Typically, refresh tokens are only used with confidential clients.
>   However, since it is possible to use the authorization code flow
>   without a client secret, the refresh grant may also be used by clients
>   that don’t have a secret. If the client was issued a secret, then the
>   client must authenticate this request. Typically the service will
>   allow either additional request parameters client_id and
>   client_secret, or accept the client ID and secret in the HTTP Basic
>   auth header. If the client does not have a secret, then no client
>   authentication will be present in this request.

This means that refresh tokens might not be the right choice for a client app that should not store credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think I am going to replace Passport with jwt package. This will suit probably more for me.